Suction Whistles
Dr Theodore Folsom built a Pipe Harmonica (US Patent 2754714, 1952), in which two whistles are attached to a single airway. One whistle is sounded by blowing, the other by inhaling. Sam Hinton can be seen playing one of these instruments at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jEXi8pqlZKY. Sam's instrument is made from tin plate. Folsom's patent figure 2 show a wooden version. The patent shows the inner construction of the two whistles. The blown whistle can be reproduced, but matching the tone of the suction whistle is not easy - it appears to use a different fluid mechanism. Can anyone shed light on the mechanics of this suction whistle, or point to information concerning whistle tones produced by suction?
In figure 2 of patent 2754714, [12] is the mouthpiece opening, [22] is the wind-way. The pipe nearest the wind-way sounds when the user inhales, the pipe furthest from the wind-way sounds when the user exhales.

